# Custom validations for non persisted model in Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, ruby-on-rails-4, activemodel

After have read (almost) all internet I need you input in this problem.

**Context:** 
I have a [non persisted Rails 4 model](http://blog.isnorcreative.com/2014/05/08/easier-non-activerecord-models-in-rails-4.html) using [ActiveModel::Model](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Model.html) that, according to its documentation, includes [ActiveModel::Validations](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Validations.html)

**Code:**

```
class GoodnessValidator < ActiveModel::Validator
  def validate(record)
    if record.first_name == "Evil"
      record.errors[:base] << "This person is evil"
    end
  end
end

class Person
  include ActiveModel::Model
  include ActiveModel::Validations

  validates_with GoodnessValidator
  attr_accessor :first_name
end
```

**Problem:** 
When I'll create a new `Person` as `p = Person.new(first_name: 'Evil')` should be validate that is an "evil person". So, I expect an error accessor like `p.errors` which should return me a `Hash` with all errors.

But, always is empty, `p.errors` don't returns nothing. Never.

```
[102] pry(main)> p = Person.new(first_name: 'Evil')
=> #<Person:0x007fa0925809f0 @first_name="Evil">
[103] pry(main)> p.errors
=> #<ActiveModel::Errors:0x007fa09173ac88 @base=#<Person:0x007fa0925809f0 @errors=#<ActiveModel::Errors:0x007fa09173ac88 ...>, @first_name="Evil">, @messages={}>
[104] pry(main)> p.errors.full_messages
=> []
[105] pry(main)>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The validations are normally triggered when you save the model. In your case, you need to run them manually, then check the errors:

```
p = Person.new(first_name: 'Evil')
unless p.valid? # runs the validations
  puts inspect p.errors
end
```

Comment: And conversely there is also an `invalid?` method which triggers validation too.

Comment: Ohhh, good point! you are right, validator is a Class that must be instantiated before and valid? do it